# Ionic 3 angular Http call not working on IOS device and simulators

Tags: ios, oauth, ionic2, ionic3, angular-http

I am developing application using Ionic framework and angular Http for Webservice calls. My application is working fine on android devices, but not on IOS devices. After deploy the application on IOS devices, while making webservice calls getting response status as 0. 
   Already implemented **NSAppTransportSecurity** in the config file and it is reflecting correctly on -Info.plist file. Also i am using following cordova plugins.

1. ionic-plugin-keyboard
2. cordova-sqlite-storage
3. cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1
4. cordova-plugin-splashscreen
5. cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.11
6. cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
7. cordova-plugin-dialogs
8. cordova-plugin-device

Also adding following headers while making request
 'Authorization':   something
 'X-Requested-With' :  something
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS", 
 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "Content-Type"

and ionic info is as follows:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.16.0-alpha.fb4e38e9
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.16.0-alpha.fb4e38e9
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2 ios 4.3.1 windows 5.0.0 wp8 (deprecated)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 24.3.4
Node              : v8.9.4
npm               : 5.3.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

I am using normal webview only not a WKWebview.

Can anybody has any idea about this?

Thanks
AK

Comment: Have you tried https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ ?

Comment: not yet. But if angular http is working means why we should go for ionic native http? Is it mandatory for IOS?

Comment: If you look on the internet more people have this problem. I found this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic3-angular-http-not-working-in-ios-help-me/110575/5). Maybe its something wrong with the headers on the server you try to reach? It's weird that it works on Android tho and not on ios. It could also still be that you didnt configure the config.xml right?

Comment: There is a problem for adding ** NSAppTransportSecurity** and it is fixed now and working fine. The code should like as follows `<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="replace" target="NSAppTransportSecurity">
            <dict>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true />
            </dict>
        </edit-config>`